# how to fix makeparam and train error in r?

Tags: r, shiny, frameworks

I'm getting following errors:

> Warning in `makeParam(id = id, type = "numeric", learner.param = TRUE, lower = lower,`  :
>             NA used as a default value for learner parameter missing.
>           ParamHelpers uses NA as a special value for dependent parameters.

```
[Tune] Started tuning learner regr.xgboost for parameter set:
                    Type len Def      Constr Req Tunable Trafo
max_depth        integer   -   -     5 to 15   -    TRUE     -
lambda           numeric   -   - 0.05 to 0.5   -    TRUE     -
eta              numeric   -   - 0.01 to 0.5   -    TRUE     -
subsample        numeric   -   -    0.5 to 1   -    TRUE     -
min_child_weight numeric   -   -     2 to 10   -    TRUE     -
colsample_bytree numeric   -   -  0.5 to 0.8   -    TRUE     -
With control class: TuneControlRandom
Imputation value: Inf
```